# Two-way ANOVA repeated measures

Tags: anova, data-visualization, spss, interaction

I would like to know, if you got a significant interaction in a two-way repeated measures ANOVA in SPSS, how can you visualize the interaction (especially using syntax)?

Answer (score 1):

Just plot the profile,

From: http://psychweb.psy.umt.edu/denis/datadecision/simple_effects_SPSS/index.html

glm count by condition age. 
/plot = profile(condition*age)

Comment: Isn't that for independent groups, not repeated measures?

Comment: yeah, but the profile command should still work from mixed , don't have the software to verify that at the moment though